# angular4 subscribe to a web service

Tags: angular, web-services, rxjs, google-custom-search

I have a web service calling Google Custom Search API in Angular4 (using Observable), and I call it in my component (through an Observer and mergemap operator). The whole functionality also involves Material Design md-input and ng-ngx-bootstrap Typeahead.
Everything is done in the `OnInit`, which triggers a call to my google search service with an empty query each time the page is opened/refreshed.
How can I trigger the call to my search service only if a `string` is passed as parameter? I quite a newbie to Angular4 and RxJS Observable, my code may not be totally right, so I'm open to comments/ideas/suggestions.

**Component:**

```
public value = '';
public dataSource: Observable<any>;
public subs: Subscription;

constructor(private searchService: SearchService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = Observable
    .create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      observer.next(this.value);
      observer.complete();
    })
    .mergeMap((token: string) => this.searchService.getSearch(this.value));
  this.subs = this.dataSource.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}
```

**Template:**

```
<md-input-container class="w-75">
  <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="value"
    [typeahead]="dataSource"
    (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
    (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
    (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
    typeaheadOptionsLimit="10"
    typeaheadOptionField="title"
    typeaheadWaitMs="250"
    typeaheadMinLength="3"
    [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customItemTemplate"
    placeholder="Entrez votre recherche ici">
  <span *ngIf="typeaheadLoading===true"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i></span>
  <div *ngIf="typeaheadNoResults===true">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aucun résultat.
  </div>
  <md-hint align="end">rechercher dans la sphère éducative</md-hint>
</md-input-container>
<button type="submit" [routerLink]="resultUrl()" md-mini-fab><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Comment: Try to look into ngModelChange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line

```
.mergeMap((token: string) => this.searchService.getSearch(this.value));
```

with

```
.mergeMap((token: string) => token ? this.searchService.getSearch(this.value) : Observable.of([]));
```

So your service will only be called when there is any token or search term else you return an empty array

Comment: It works! Tank you very much Karan, I tried to find out what was the role of that token.

Comment: here token is the term you type into your input(typeahead)

Comment: if the solution worked for you then you can mark it as the useful/best so that the question can be useful to other users also

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks for your support.